# FullCalendar timeGridWeek dragging or selecting time slot stops working towards end of day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using Fullcalendar timeGridWeek side by side with dayGrid.

I can drag between the two and resize or drag in the timeGridWeek (the one on the left).

However, the problem is functionality is broken after hour 6PM or towards the end of the day, depending on the screen width.

I've also enabled clicking on time slot. I can click until 13:00. Anything after that stops working.

If I set the `#container > *` element to 1600px (on my ultrawide display) everything works correctly.

I can't figure out why.

I also have this running in a React App with MaterialUI and it behaves in the same way. I presumed it was something to do with the theme, but now can see it does the same thing with minimal styling.

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exabpW?editors=0010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a confirmed bug: references here

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4503

and here

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4505

Answer (score 0):

This might come from the `businessHours` option, at pair with the `eventConstraint: 'businessHours'` option, which, if both are set together, disallow dragging and moving outside businessHours.

So the way to patch it would be to remove the `eventConstraint` option if u placed it, or change your `businessHours`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. According to the docs here (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/businessHours) the businessHours option "Emphasizes certain time slots on the calendar. By default, Monday-Friday, 9am-5pm.". 


Which by default is 


`boolean / object. default: false`


So since it's not on, it doesn't appear to be it. I just set it to off explicitly. As mentioned in the original question, on a very wide screen, all works well...

Comment: I don't know then, maybe an issue with css media queries ? or fullCalendar itself locks moving events for elements under a certain size

Comment: I suspected CSS but am not sure anymore. Might be a bug. I'll report it on their github repo.